# Is it possible to create a User-Defined hierarchy between dimension attributes that are unrelated?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, business-intelligence

I am working on spiking out a BI solution and I am trying to create a Hierarchy in out 'Client' dimension more or less to replicate what I know the end users will do.

The Client dimension table has 3 foreign key relationships with other tables, each of these relationships are standalone from the others. They are Role, Service Type, and Status.

Whenever this dimension will be used it will almost always be with the Role attribute first so I tried to create hierarchies like Role -> Service Type -> Client. Now when I try to process with this setup I get the error "The  table that is required for a join cannot be reached based on the relationships in the data source view"

Is there any way to create a Hierarchy with disparate attributes like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to build a hierarchy across multiple dimensions that are not related to one another in that way.

One option would be to restructure your schema to a Star schema rather than a Snowflake schema. If that's not an option, depending on the details you might be able to build a query in SSAS or a view in SQL server, and then create a dimension in SSAS from that.

From the information given it's hard to judge whether Role, Service Type, and Status should be in separate tables, but have a good think about this. Should the attributes you want to use from them actually be attributes of Client? Would doing this allow you to get rid of some of those tables and/or reduce the amount of Snowflaking? Remember that dimensional models are very different from a normal relational model: the aim is to keep the number of joins low, and it can be acceptable to repeat attributes in different tables if that's going to be more efficient. Of course, sometimes restructuring just isn't a realistic prospect, which is where a query or view might come in useful to work around this issue.

I've been learning SSAS recently myself, and have found that when I'm struggling to get something working in SSAS, the problem is very often the underlying schema not being set up in the best way for what I'm trying to accomplish.

(Apologies if this is a little vague but it's difficult to be more detailed without knowing the nature of the data, and I don't yet have the ability to comment and ask for more information!)